# substitute of count(*) OVER () in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

this is my SQL server query

```
` Select top 8
count(id) OVER () as speccount,
(SELECT count(*) From Profile_Master pm WHERE CONCAT(pm.fname , pm.lname) LIKE '%'+@keyword+'%' and
(select Top 1 city from DAddress_Master where profileid=pm.id)=@city) as drcount,
(SELECT count(*) From  DAddress_Master dam  WHERE dam.city=@city and dam.clinicname LIKE '%'+@keyword+'%') as cliniccount,
specialization AS name,
id as id,
'Specialization' as type,
'' as drspec
From Specialization_Master 
Where specialization LIKE '%'+@keyword+'%'`
```

actually part of my whole query. now i have to convert this query into mysql, which not that much big deal, but can some one tell substitute of **count(*) OVER ()**  in mysql?

I came across to this functions.

> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
>   and SELECT FOUND_ROWS();

but is there another way??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably a subquery:

```
select (select count(*) from Specialization where specialization LIKE '%'+@keyword+'%'`
       ) as speccnt
```

Note:  if you are switching databases and you are using functionality such as window functions, you might consider Postgres rather than MySQL, because Postgres supports window functions.